# Double integral given change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Let $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 < a \leq x \} $. Show that 
$$ \iint_{D} e^{-(x^2 + a^2 )} \, dx \, dy = ae^{-a^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u^2}}{u^2 + a^2} \,du $$
using the change of variables $x^2 + y^2 = u^2 + a^2 $ and $y = vx$.

I found the Jacobian to be $\frac{u}{1+v^2}$ and the limits of integration $0 < u < \infty$ and  $\frac{-u}{a} < v < \frac{u}{a}$. This leads me to
$$ \iint_D e^{(x^2 + a^2 )} \, dx \, dy = \int_0^\infty \int_{\frac{-u}{a}}^{\frac{u}{a}}  e^{-(u^2+a^2)}\frac{u}{1+v^2} \, dv \, du $$
I can see how $e^{-a^2}$ factors out, but if I just integrate with respect to $v$  I end up with some $\arctan\left(\frac{u}{a}\right).$

I think I have to make another another substituition and call it $u$ as well, but I couldn't think of a good one.

Comment: I'm confused about the limits of integration. Should it be $0<x\le a$?

Comment: No. The question states $ 0 < a \leq x$

Comment: So I'm interpreting this as $x$ and $y$ are defined for all reals. Integrate a from 0 to x, and don't do anything about y. Could you clean me up please?

Comment: You are supposed to integrate $x$ from $a$ to $\infty$ and $y$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$